# Klaxon Error on Converting List<objects> to jsonString

Tags: kotlin, klaxon

in the Kotlin language android development application, I try to use Klaxon to convert my list of objects to JSON string.
my code work without error on debugging but after release it has error on JsonArray(queryResult).toJsonString()

**error is: No accessors or field is found for property var ea.c.: kotlin.String?**

queryResult here is List

is there any special permission I missed to apply for release?